# filter array of strings based on priorities javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

const array = {
"clientName": "xyz",
"exp": 0,
"roles": [
"dist-users",
"admin-dev"
]
};

I want to filter roles based on priority as admin-* then 2nd priority as dist-users, if none present then by default dist-users.How to achieve that?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` iterates over all elements - you can't stop it.

I don't think this is the right approach, you should use `Array.find` or `Array.findIndex` to probe the `roles` array and figure out if it has an item starting with the desired prefix.

```js
const array = {
    "clientName": "xyz",
    "exp": 0,
    "prefUserName": "admin-dev",
    "roles": [
        "dist-users",
        "admin-dev"
    ]
};

const admin = array.roles.find(role => role.includes('admin-'))
const dist = array.roles.find(role => role.includes('dist-users'))

const roles = [ admin || dist || 'dist-users' ]

console.log(roles)
```

Comment: “Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.” - Arthur C Clarke ;-)